# I can't seem to find the missing "("

Tags: sql

So I made some SQL code getting the tables of movies by years and so on.

Here is what it looks like:

```
year1 as Decade 
   from
   (
      Select
         year1,
         sum(total_movies2) as Total,
         row_number() over (
      order by
         sum(total_movies2) desc) as row 
      from
         (
            Select
               CAST(SUBSTR(TRIM(year), - 4) AS INTEGER) as Year1,
               count(MID) as Total_Movies1 
            From
               Movie 
            Group by
               CAST(SUBSTR(TRIM(year), - 4) AS INTEGER) 
         )
         a 
         join
            (
               Select
                  CAST(SUBSTR(TRIM(year), - 4) AS INTEGER) as Year2,
                  count(MID) as Total_Movies2 
               From
                  Movie 
               Group by
                  CAST(SUBSTR(TRIM(year), - 4) AS INTEGER) 
            )
            b 
            on a.year1 <= b.year2 
            and a.year1 + 9 >= b.year2 
      Group by
         year1 
   )
where
   row = 1
```

I went to run the code, but I got this error:

```
Syntax Error : ': near "(": syntax error
```

I went to check all the brackets/parentheses in my code, but I don't seem to find the problem. Can anyone spot it for me? Where should I put the missing `(`?

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: you should simply count the number of `(` and `)`. That should not be too hard?

Comment: Tried formating , and found it right. But getting error on Google colab

Comment: The syntax error is likely just before a `(` where the parser then stops.

Answer (score 0):

So I realized that the only unpaired parentheses is `)` from the end.
[image: CS50 Sandbox Screenshot (indicated the code from a previous revision)]

You should put `(` before the lines `(Select CAST(SUBSTR(TRIM(year), - 4) AS INTEGER) as Year2, count(MID) ...`.